# Asserting element Id uniqueness globally with XML 1.1 schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it possible to use XML 1.1 schema to verify that that no two elements in a document share an id. For example, the attached XML document should fail because the id's 0, 1 and 3 are not unique.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item>
    <c id="0"/>  <!-- error: shared id -->
    <a id="1"/>  <!-- error: shared id -->
    <a id="2"/>
    <b id="3"/>  <!-- error: shared id -->
    <a id="4"/>
    <b id="0"/>  <!-- error: shared id -->
    <d id="6"/>
    <d id="7"/>
    <b id="3"/>  <!-- error: shared id -->
    <c id="1"/>  <!-- error: shared id -->
</Item>
```

Schema, to be convert to XML 1.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Item">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:choice>

                    <xs:element name="a">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="b">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="c">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="d">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:attribute name="id" use="required"/>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need XSD 1.1 for this, it can be done with XSD 1.0. In the element definition for Item, add a uniqueness constraint:

```
<xs:unique name="unique-id">
  <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
  <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
</xs:unique>
```

Comment: In retrospect, my actual schema is now peppered with `xs:unique`'s, having made up names, due to nested elements. It would be nice if the `xs:unique` can be carried along with an `xs:simpleType` or `xs:complexType`.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. I've only just realized that it suffices to place `<xs:selector xpath=".//*"/>` in the top level element.