# XSD 1.1 structure to enforce unique IDs (if necessary)?

Tags: xml, validation, uniqueidentifier, xsd-1.1

Do I need XSD 1.1 to enforce ID uniqueness in a single XML file with a file/record structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<file>

<record id="1" status="ok">
    <info1></info1>
    <info2></info2>
    <!-- etc... -->
</record>

<record id="2" status="ok">
    <info1></info1>
    <info2></info2>
    <!-- etc... -->
</record>

<record id="1" status="duplicate_deprecated">
    <info1></info1>
    <info2></info2>
    <!-- etc... -->
</record>
```

I'd like to also allow certain duplicated IDs under the condition that they are combined with e.g. an attribute meaning "remove / stop using this version of the record, replace this (now) deprecated duplicate by the other record with the same ID" (in the example, record 1).

Is this possible with XML schema 1.0 or does it need XSD 1.1 assertions (etc.)?

What kind of general XML instance structure is needed to make this assertion work? I know that XSD 1.1 asserts need to be on closely related elements / attributes.

Possibly related:

- [Asserting element Id uniqueness globally with XML 1.1 schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496989/asserting-element-id-uniqueness-globally-with-xml-1-1-schema)
- [XSD unique elements and attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532872/xsd-unique-elements-and-attributes)

Comment: I'd love to get some comments here as to how I can lose the downvotes!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this needs XSD 1.1. Unfortunately the XPath expressions you can use on xs:unique / xs:key don't include predicates (even in XSD 1.1) so this can only be done with assertions.

The typical way of asserting uniqueness is

```
test="count(PATH) = count(distinct-values(PATH))"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't give any diagnostics about what the offending duplicates are. Some processors might give you better diagnostics with

```
test="every $M in PATH, $N in PATH satisfies ($M is $N or $M ne $N)"
```

but this is likely to be much less efficient.

The assertion should be specified on the innermost element that contains all the values to be tested for uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you Michael, this is great. Even without a diagnostic, it's extremely helpful.

Comment: So in the example above, the assertion should be in the definition of `<record>` as this contains the `id` attribute?

Comment: ...and a similar counting test could be specified to account for the set of "excused" duplicate ids...? Wonderful.

Comment: You can specify the excluded items in a predicate within the path, e.g. PATH might be `.//record[not(@status='excluded')/@id`

Comment: It has to be defined on the element that includes ALL the ids, i.e. in your case `<file>`.

Comment: Thanks. This was partly a question to help me get the XML mindset wrt this design issue and your answer really did that.

Comment: I just discovered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496989/asserting-element-id-uniqueness-globally-with-xml-1-1-schema

Comment: Similar, but it lacks the critical aspect of excluding some elements from the uniqueness check.

Comment: Thank you again Mr. Kay. I'm still trying to get a demo instance + XSD to validate (or not) in oxygen; once that's running I'll light up the green tick.